# LaTeX align stacked summation

Tags: latex, equation, alignment

I am writing an elementary summation proof and would like to write that

```
  1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-2 + n-1 + n
+ n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 3 + 2 + 1
= n+1 + n+1 + n+1 + ...
```

and so on.  I want the symbols to line up so that it's easy to see the vertical addition.  How do I do this in LaTeX?  The `align` environment doesn't do so well with multiple things to align on, and creating a `tabular` environment is annoying because it's not in math mode.

Comment: Great question for tex.stackexchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `array` environment is the way to go here. This solution is better in some ways than Jack Kelly's, and worse in other ways:

```
\begin{array}{c *{6}{c@{\hspace{6pt} + \hspace{6pt}}} c}
    & 1   & 2   & 3   & \ldots & n-2 & n-1 & n   \\
  + & n   & n-1 & n-2 & \ldots & 3   & 2   & 1   \\
  = & n+1 & n+1 & n+1 & \ldots & n+1 & n+1 & n+1
\end{array}
```

Two things to notice in the column specification: we use `*{6}{spec}` to get six copies of a column with specification `spec`.  We also use `@` to specify that each column separator should look like a six-point gap, a plus sign, and another gap.

More on the `@` trick [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#.40-expressions).

Comment: I don't see how it is worse. Less flexible, but much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

My LaTeX is a little rusty, but here goes:

```
\[
\begin{array}{l r c r c r c c c r c r c r}
    & 1 & + & 2 & + & 3 & + & \ldots & + & n-2 & + & n-1 & + & n \\
  + & n & + & n-1 & + & n-2 & + & \ldots & + & 3 & + & 2 & + & 1 \\
  = & n+1 & + & n+1 & + & n+1 & + & \ldots & + & n+1 & + & n+1 & + & n+1\\
\end{array}
\]
```

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about the array environment.  Thanks!